# linux - how to sample CPU usage between events

Tags: performance-testing, perf, ebpf

I'd like to do something like "perf record -g -p PID -- sleep 60", but to limit the stack sampling to certain periods of time, in order to avoid noise from the many threads running in the application.

So the idea is that whenever function X() runs on thread T, I start taking cpu samples on thread T until function Y() runs on the same thread. The output can be limited to cpu% of each function - with and without callees.

As an alternative to this selective sampling, I may record all samples and filter the ones that are not of interest in a post-processing stage.

Any ideas on how to accomplish this?

Comment: If the noise comes from threads, why not limit recording to a thread instead?

Comment: @zulan I don't know the thread in advance - it's a multi-threaded Java application server (I'm trying to profile mostly native code though). Even in the same thread there can be multiple requests served, and I'm interested in a specific one.

Comment: Can you change `X` to run custom code? ... say `perf record -g -t MY_TID`?

Comment: @zulan that's a great idea! I was looking for something that would also work for short periods of time (~300ms), but my biggest problem is something that takes 17 seconds, so running perf (and sending a SIGINT when I hit Y()) will actually work very well. Also for a very short period of time, not sure what value perf has as it's sampling. Thanks!